# Log JSON field when clicking on a table row

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-framework-7

I am using [Framework7](https://framework7.io/docs/) to build a mobile app. Using the [popup](https://framework7.io/docs/popup.html) and [request](https://framework7.io/docs/request.html) features, I am dynamically building an html table with JSON data as follows:

```
//Do something when popup is opened
$$(document).on('popup:opened', '.popup-airconSearch', function (e) {
  //Show preloader 
  app.preloader.show();
  //Request json data from URL
  app.request.json('my-URL', function (data) {
    var tableHtml = '';
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1){
        tableHtml+= '<tr><td class="numeric-only">' +data[i].brand+ '</td> <td class="numeric- only">' +data[i].model+ '</td></tr>';        
      }
    //Add rows to HTML table    
    $$('.data-table #airconDatabase').html(tableHtml);
    app.preloader.hide();    
  })
})
```

The JSON URL also includes an ID field and I am trying to log the ID of each entry when a table row is clicked. I have updated the above function with:

```
$$('.data-table #airconDatabase tr').on('click', e => {      
  var id = data[i].regnumber;
  console.log (id);      
})
```

However the console logs ID as underfined. If I change it to

```
var id = data[0].regnumber;
```

Then the first JSON entry regnumber field is logged to console no matter which table row is clicked. If I change it to

```
var id = data[1].regnumber;
```

Then the second JSON entry regnumber field is logged and so on.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: whats i in var id = data[i].regnumber , you also need to loop through , like you did in above steps

Comment: @KaranTewari I see. However if I use the same loop through in the above steps then the console logs the regnumber field for all of the entries and not just the entry in the table row that has been clicked on.

Comment: Outside of the request part you don't have access to the data-object. So you have to include some kind of id or data-attribute in your table html, which you can pick up later.

Comment: Thanks @Joerg see my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

Firstly build the dynamic HTML table with a row ID from the JSON data:

```
tableHtml+= '<tr id="' +data[i].am_5_regnumber+ '"><td class..
```

Then get the row ID when a table row is clicked:

```
$$('.data-table #airconDatabaseTable tbody tr').on('click', function (e) {
    var zaf = $$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    console.log (zaf);       
  })
```

In addition to the above, I had to add an ID to the HTML table and not just the table body.